# How to calculate sample size for more than two groups for continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, sample-size, multiple-comparisons

I would like to know how to calculate the sample size that will compare 3 treatment groups. Treatment 1, treatment 2 and Placebo. This is a completely hypothetical scenario.
In scenario 1 I would like to compare all treatments to placebo against a binary endpoint:
Here are the expected success rates: `Treatment 1: 50%` `Treatment 2: 30%` and `Placebo: 15%.`

Scenario 2: This time I want to compare a continuous variable between the 3 groups. Here are the expected means `Treatment 1 mean:115` `treatment 2 mean: 90` `treatment 3 mean: 80`. I assume an equal `variance of 20`.

```
Alpha and Beta remain classic: 5 and 80%.
```

So I have a few questions and technical aids to ask;
1:Could I have links to some literature on sample size when you have several groups. I haven't found anything that would enlighten me.

2: How to implement with R software the calculation of the number of subjects needed for the different scenarios presented above.

3: If I plan to do multiple comparison tests:
In case 1, comparing each treatment with the control group (two tests)
In case 2, by comparing each group with each other (three tests)
Do I need to adjust the sample size calculation for the number of tests I want to perform?

Or is doing an alpha risk correction test (Like Tukey or Bonferonni) without any adjustment sufficient to prove a difference between each treatment pair if a global difference is found by anova?

Comment: Does the [vignette for the pwr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html) help you get started? Re: 3) No, you don't need to do p-value adjustments in sample size calculations. Just do them when you actually conduct your analyses.